# Доступ к редактированию через проверку поля (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, доступ

Есть ли возможность проверять привилегии по определенному полю?
Например у меня в материале есть поле field_access связанное с юзерами, которое принимает ID юзера. 
Как проверять доступ к редактированию материала через него?
В данный момент редактирование возможно, только если юзер указан в авторах.

Answer (score 1):

Пачка модулей из поиска, пока не все проверял:

https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access

https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_access

https://www.drupal.org/project/access_by_ref

https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference (возможно он)

https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_conditions